# How can I change the graphics device for HTML output in R markdown without saving individual plots?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, plot, r-markdown

I am trying to compile various plots in an R markdown file.  I would prefer that the HTML output produced images using scalable vector graphics instead of the default PNG images.  Currently, I am using the following method to achieve this:

````
---
title: "SVG Plot Test"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup-chunk}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "svg")
```

```{r test_plot}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Temp, y = Wind)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

However, when I knit these chunks to HTML, an additional folder is created and the plot is saved within that folder as well.  With the large number of plots I am creating, I'd prefer not to save these copies as well, since they are already present within the resulting HTML document.

How can I prevent these additional files from being created while still getting svg output in the HTML file?

Comment: Try setting `cache=FALSE` in chunks that generate plots? Hard to say for sure without a reproducible example (in this case, a minimal `.Rmd`).

Comment: I believe that cache=FALSE is the default option, so that should already apply to the above example.  How is the code above not a reproducible example?  Knitting the two chunks in a .Rmd file produces the saved plots, as I described.  Is there additional information that is needed?

Comment: Edit: I've updated the example above to be a bit more readable.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I am not able to reproduce the issue. `rmarkdown::render(<name>.Rmd)` generates `<name>.html` correctly _without_ saving the SVG in my working directory, which is what I expect, because, as you say, `cache` is `FALSE` by default.

Comment: Oh wait...  My apologies.  It appears that caching does have something to do with the issue I'm having.  (That'll teach me to test my "reproducible" examples beforehand...)  I don't have time right this moment to update this question, but I'll come back to it as soon as I can.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thank you for helping me better understand how R markdown handles caching and saving plots, and I apologize again for not initially putting more thought into the question I asked.  I realize now that the question I really want answered is quite different from this one, so I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70270796/15319349).  Your input would be much appreciated!